# Error on trying to use CV2 for capturing video from WebCam

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I am trying to make an application that makes use of the Webcam to get the video. But when I run the program, the webcam doesn't start and I don't see the cv2 window open. I even tried making a simple webcam program, but it isn't working either:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (436) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

My webcam works fine in other application. Only cv2 is having problem. what should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no frame to convert to grayscale.
How about try this.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#change to your video path
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("D:\start.mp4")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if (ret!=True):
         break

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: it still doesn't start the webcam. I get the warning before and the program terminates

Comment: it isn't going into the while loop. `cap.isOpened()` is returnng false

Comment: ah, you should put video path at 4th line like this
     cap = cv2.VideoCapture("D:\start.mp4")

Comment: but I am not reading a video file, I am trying to capture webcam video

Answer (score 0):

The program you use is the "hello the world" of the video or the blink led or arduino.

So I experienced the same problem than you and the answer is .. bad driver for your camera.

when I bought my very expensive camera (20$) I install the driver and every thing was working fine with  opencv.

I experimented recently nightmare with my WIFI and I start to uninstall drivers .

I finally solve my problems of WIFI YES !!!
And then I reinstall my drivers include the video BUT
My cat has scratched the original installation disk of the video , ok so I let windows install a generic driver.

Everything seems fine, sound and image, good  (what else do you ask for a 20$ camera)

After some time I come back to openCV and then...same error

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

I look at all the forums test every thing I could install other version and all that "magic tricks" time consuming (but you learn a lot this is the good side of it)
Totally desperate I remember that I did not install the original driver
BINGO
I went to the shop because this oem product did not have internet address to load the driver GRGRGRGRgrrgrgrgr
and everything work perfect now
Small tips
with the generic driver I was often obliged to disconnect and reconnect my camera with this test
https://www.onlinemictest.com/webcam-test/
(not sure if it this site is clean use it at tour own risk)
So install a driver adapted to your camera and stop to doubt about opencv and your installation
My 5 cents.

Comment: But my camera works on other applications just fine. so why only OpenCV is having problem? rather OpenCV was also working back few months back, but when I formatted my laptop and reinstalled it, now it is giving problems

Comment: My camera work also with the generic driver but not good enough
what driver do you have for your camera ?
I bet that you have a generic driver not the driver specific for your camera
If, like me, you just use it for contact friends, you do not care if some function does not work, boy openCV does care !!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there could be a timing issue between the camera starting up and the code entering the while loop. I ran into the exact same issue and was stumped.

I even had a previous code that worked (in a different project). So I tried adding an extra read before entering the while loop.

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
white True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # rest of the code
```

This worked. Then I wanted to see if this indeed fixes it. I removed the `cap.read()` before the while loop and re-ran the code. Now it continued working.

I am thinking that camera to start and be read by the program once before it can start instantly.